# Return 4 row of np array where the values are the biggest in column 1

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following array `MyArray` :

```
[['AZ' 0.144]
 ['RZ' 14.021]
 ['BH' 1003.487]
 ['NE' 1191.514]
 ['FG' 550.991]
 ['MA' nan]]
```

Where Array dim is :

```
MyArray.shape
(6,2)
```

How would I return the 4 Row where values are the biggest ?

So the output would be :

```
[['RZ' 14.021]
 ['BH' 1003.487]
 ['NE' 1191.514]
 ['FG' 550.991]]
```

I tried :

```
MyArray[np.argpartition(MyArray, -2)][:-4]
```

But this does return an error :

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: If you are working with heterogenous collections, such as the example you provided, it is probably better to use regular python lists with `import heapq; heapq.nlargest(4, MyArray, lambda x: x[1])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just sort by second column and get last 4 rows:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(
    [['AZ', 0.144],
     ['RZ', 14.021],
     ['BH', 1003.487],
     ['NE', 1191.514],
     ['FG', 550.991],
     ['MA', np.nan]],
)

a = a[~np.isnan(a[:, 1].astype(float))]
srt = a[a[:, 1].astype(float).argsort()]
print(srt[-4:, :])
```

Comment: Amazing one, totally what I was struggling to do, will accept asap. And already upvoted

Comment: I shortened this answer a bit. @MSH if you don't approve, revert :)

Comment: @richardec Nope. Now it looks better. Than you.

Comment: This confuses me a bit. When I `print(srt)`, the rows are not sorted by the second column numerically...

Comment: @richardec After your comment I realized the because of how `numpy` work, the second column is `str` type. That's why I had to convert it to float on the line you corrected. Now, on sorting line we have to convert it to float too. Otherwise it will be string and sorting string is done differently. I fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with a remark on how to create *MyArray*:
You have to pass `dtype=object`, otherwise the array is of *<U8* type.

Start the computation with setting the number of rows to retrieve:

```
n = 4
```

Then get the result running:

```
result = MyArray[np.argpartition(MyArray[:, 1], n)[:n]]
```

The result is:

```
array([['AZ', 0.144],
       ['RZ', 14.021],
       ['FG', 550.991],
       ['BH', 1003.487]], dtype=object)
```

How this code works:

- `np.argpartition(MyArray[:, 1], n)` retrieves `array([0, 1, 4, 2, 3, 5], dtype=int64)`.
  First 4 elements are indices of rows with 4 lowest values in column *1*.
- `…[:n]` - leaves only the indices of the lowest rows.
- `MyArray[…]` - retrieves the indicated rows.

Other possible solution, maybe easier to comprehend:

```
result = np.take(MyArray, np.argpartition(MyArray[:, 1], n)[:n], axis=0)
```